# How do we back up affirmative answers to "Am I understanding this correctly"-style questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, citations

A new user left [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147423/40335) to the [Can Heighten Spell benefit a [Reserve] feat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36319/can-heighten-spell-benefit-a-reserve-feat):

> Legal and working as intended.

I found this question (and answer) when looking through the review queue, and there was already the standard "Don't give a one line answer" boilerplate on the given answer.

I was about to comment saying "hey, welcome, can you elaborate on this answer?" when I realized that with questions that boil down to "here's a situation, am I understanding the rules/etc correctly?" all the answers are going to boil down to either "no, and here's where you went wrong" - which is fine - and "yeah, you got it right"... But in the latter case, how *do* you elaborate on that?

How do we back up affirmative answers to "Am I understanding this correctly"-style questions?

Comment: Related metas (sort of the opposite of this): [What is an acceptable form for a “no” answer to a question of the form “Does X exist in the lore?”](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8265/33569), [What To Do When There Are No Right Answers, Only Wrong Ones](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8033/33569), [Whether to answer or not if one believes there is no answer possible](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5530/33569)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Support *why* they are correct

Add the full rule context and explain the rule to the best of your ability. Usually these kind of questions come from a misunderstanding or lack of comprehension of the rules. You should try to clear up their confusion as well as directly answer the question.

If possible draw parallels to other rules from the system that use the same mechanic, or contrast with one that works differently.

Use *emphasis* or **bold** on the specific parts of the rules that mean it works the way it does.

If the question is somewhat subjective. Remember to follow the guidelines of [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Support your answer with experience of how you have applied this ruling at the table and how it worked out.

A one-line unsupported answer is not useful to anyone. Anybody can just say "yeah that works". SE answers need to *prove* that it works.

Comment: What if the question has already done all of this?

Comment: Doesn't matter. You need to support your answer, otherwise it is just noise.

Comment: @sevenbrokenbricks That particular question is difficult to answer well without repeating parts of the question yes. However there are 3 visible answers and 2 deleted ones that support their views. So it is possible to do better than leave a one line answer.

Comment: I was about to say that the accepted answer doesn't do a whole lot more, but then I saw the answer that said "yes, this works, but no, it's not the overpowered cheese you think it is" and realized that this was the "misunderstanding or lack of comprehension" by the querent that you cited. Makes a lot more sense now, thank you!